# Asp.net c# saving a variable with onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, variables, onclick

I have a foreach that displays all the thumbnail images from a list of Image objects (every object has name, path, description, title etc.).

```
  foreach {
  <a href="#Gallery" title="<%= image.Description %>" rel="imgGallery">
  <img src="<%= image.GetVariantFilePath("Small") %>" alt="<%= image.Description %>" />
  }
```

Now I have to display the image of the clicked thumbnail on another part of the page.
Which is the best way to do it? I was thinking of using an onclick event and javascript, but I'm not sure at all.
Any example?

Update1: I'm using jquery fancybox, but I have to customise it in the way that I can show the gallery thumbnails in the lightbox under the clicked image. So that I'm just displaying the thumbnails somewhere, and when I click on an image, it opens the lightbox with a div in which I manage all the logic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript and jquery to display this image elsewhere on the page providing that the src to the normal page where fixed.

```
foreach { 
   <a id='image' href="#Gallery" title="<%= image.Description %>" rel="imgGallery"  largeSrc='<%//large file path %>'>
   <img src="<%= image.GetVariantFilePath("Small") %>" alt="<%= image.Description %>" />
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#image").click(function(){
     var largeSrc = $(this).attr('largeSrc');
     $('#LargeImageId').attr('src', largeSrc);
});
```

Comment: Well the link in the for loop will be used.  So in the jquery, the $("image").click is the event handler whenever this is clicked.  The event handler will then use the largeSrc to set the other image src.  You can add animation if you want.  This was a simple quick solution.  Hope that makes more sense?

Answer (score 2):

How about using [lightbox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)?

Comment: You could use an ASP.NET Web Handler File (ashx) that dynamically returns the thumbnail (http://infosearchshop.com/Content.aspx?id=7vWHuJea+Lw=&title=Making+thumbnail+dynamically+with+ashx+file+in+asp.net). Then you can create an ImageLink using the thumbnail as image and opening the lightbox when clicking it. I've already done that in my homepage but unfortunately I don't have the code around right now.